# invalid cast from basic string to int type

Tags: c++, string, c++11, casting

I am getting error of type casting from basic string type to integer type and I do not know how to resolve it in the case of vector string and vector of integer type.

> below given image shows the error

```
s1[j]+=int(magazine[i]);
```

[image: this is the error]

Comment: You need to use atoi or stoi to convert string to integer.

Comment: can u explain how??

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/ and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't cast a string to integer.However,You can use stoi() to get the string numeric value and then assign it to an integer:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    string str1 = "45"; 
    string str2 = "3.14159"; 
    string str3 = "31337 geek"; 

    int myint1 = stoi(str1); 
    int myint2 = stoi(str2); 
    int myint3 = stoi(str3); 

    cout << "stoi(\"" << str1 << "\") is "
         << myint1 << '\n'; 
    cout << "stoi(\"" << str2 << "\") is "
         << myint2 << '\n'; 
    cout << "stoi(\"" << str3 << "\") is "
         << myint3 << '\n'; 

    return 0; 
} 




Output:

stoi("45") is 45
stoi("3.14159") is 3
stoi("31337 geek") is 31337
```

There are other methods too like using stringstream which you might want to look at.Hope it helps.